# I need to calculate the difference between two timestamps based on a site

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two time stamps(FIRSTOCCURRENCE and LASTOCCURRENCE) that i need to calculate the time difference in minutes based on the NODE value.

Essentially these are three fields within the table that I'm querying. How would i go about doing this?

My query looks like this

```
Select
,Node
,EventID
,FirstOCCURRENCE
,LASTOCCURRENCE
From
Reporter.reporter_status
Where firstoccurrence >= DATEADD(hh, -24 GETDATE())
```

I'm a complete nob with SQL and trying to teach myself

Trying to explain furthermore at what I'm looking to do. I need to calculate the difference between the first occurrence for Dallas on 1/03/18 and Last Occurrence for Dallas on 1/04/18. Hope this makes sense. But have different nodes so it needs to calculate the delta.

NODE       Type               First Occurrence        Last Occurrence
Dallas     Resolution         2018-01-04 12:32:02 PM  2018-01-04 12:32:32 PM
Dallas     Problem            2018:-1-03 11:22:01 AM  2018-01-03 11:22:01 AM

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be most helpful

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

```
DateDiff(MINUTE, FirstOCCURRENCE, LASTOCCURRENCE)
```

counts the number of minute boundaries between two values.  This is often sufficient.  But if you want 0 rather than 1 for 00:00:59 and 00:01:01, then go to seconds and translate back:

```
DateDiff(SECOND, FirstOCCURRENCE, LASTOCCURRENCE) / 60
```

Answer (score 0):

try using DATEDIFF([what you want to measure in being hours, min, days, years, etc], 1stOCC, 2ndOCC)

this will give you the difference.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(Day, GETDATE(), DATEADD(Hour, 641,GETDATE()))
```

`Select
,Node
,EventID
,DateDiff(MINUTE, FirstOCCURRENCE ,LASTOCCURRENCE) as [datedifference]
From
Reporter.reporter_status
Where firstoccurrence >= DATEADD(hh, -24, GETDATE())`

ive done an example for you too to play around with using a tempory table.

```
DECLARE @tmp_Accounts TABLE 
( AccountId BIGINT,AccountName VARCHAR(50), StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME)

Insert into  @tmp_Accounts VALUES (1, '1st', GETDATE(), DATEADD(Hour, 123,GETDATE()))
Insert into  @tmp_Accounts VALUES (2, '2nd', GETDATE(), DATEADD(Hour, 1,GETDATE()))
Insert into  @tmp_Accounts VALUES (3, '3rd', GETDATE(), DATEADD(Hour, 2,GETDATE()))
Insert into  @tmp_Accounts VALUES (4, '4th', GETDATE(), DATEADD(Hour, 3,GETDATE()))
Insert into  @tmp_Accounts VALUES (5, '5th', GETDATE(), DATEADD(Hour, 174,GETDATE()))

SELECT 
AccountID, 
AccountName ,
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartDate, EndDate) as [DateDifferenceInMin]
From @tmp_Accounts
```

Good luck on your SQL adventures and please dont be scared asking questions.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. So i would put all this in the query?  SELECT DATEDIFF(Day, GETDATE(), DATEADD(Hour, 641,GETDATE()))

Select
,Node
,EventID
,DateDiff(MINUTE, FirstOCCURRENCE ,LASTOCCURRENCE) as [datedifference]
From
Reporter.reporter_status
Where firstoccurrence >= DATEADD(hh, -24 GETDATE())

Comment: Yep, just place that in your query and it should run. noit knowing your data source or anything. that is why i included that temporary example to show you how it works. 

if it helps you, please mark the answer and upvote.

Comment: I updated my original question. What you provided does work, but does not provide me the data that I'm looking for. I'm trying to explain this the best i can.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the difference in minutes, then you have to say so, like this:

```
1> select datediff(minute, getdate(), dateadd(minute, 15, getdate()));
2> go

-----------
     15

(1 rows affected)
```